# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED Error when calling api with Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I have an issue in calling ajax request for web api.

```
 var url = BaseURL + 'api/endpoint'
 $.ajax({
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        Authorization : Token
    },
    processData: false,  // Important!
    dataType:"json",
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response)
    },
    error: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Working with c# mvc application calling the same api with http client success response came.

```
await client.GetAsync("api/endpoint");
```

I cannot able to find what is the error.

Web Api get method

```
[RoutePrefix("api/")]
[CustomAuthenticationFilter(Roles = "Allowed Role")]
public class MyApiController : ApiController
{
    [Route("endpoint")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetData()
    {
        GetDataDTO dto = repository.GetData();
        if (dto != null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, dto);
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new
            {
                Message = "Cannot get data"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the method declaration and maybe the body of your `Get` method as well?

Comment: have you tried testing the API by itself?